# XPATH returns null for XML with namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

I have the following XML.

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost/gsainis/GsaInisWebService">
    <string>
        <gsafeed>
            <group action="add">
                <record>
                 ......
                 ......
                </record>
            </group>
        </gsafeed>
   </string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I am using C# code (.NET 4.0) to parse this XML. I am using the code below to select all `<record>` nodes in the above XML.

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(INISRecordXMLdoc.NameTable);
xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace(string.Empty, "http://localhost/gsainis/GsaInisWebService");

foreach (XmlNode node in INISRecordXMLdoc.SelectNodes("//ArrayOfString/string/gsafeed/group/record",xmlnsmgr))
{
    //Do something
}
```

The problem is the foreach loop is never executed. What should be correct XPath to be used such that I get all the `<record>` nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this - I've had trouble in the past with having an "empty" XML prefix:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(INISRecordXMLdoc.NameTable);
xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://localhost/gsainis/GsaInisWebService");

foreach (XmlNode node in INISRecordXMLdoc.SelectNodes("//ns:ArrayOfString/ns:string/ns:gsafeed/ns:group/ns:record", xmlnsmgr))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Use something other than an empty string - and use that XML namespace prefix in your XPath.

Comment: I read about XmlNamespaceManager two days ago. And now here. Now I just need to use it my self, and it will be natural for me to use in the future :)